# what is wrong with passing from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a php code to get the message from database and i want if user click on the message an alert appears with message subject and message body using sweetalert (i have already embedded sweetalert requires)

php code

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="mine(' . $row['message_subject'] . ',' . $row['message_body'] . ');"><div class="sl-item unread-message"><div class="sl-avatar avatar avatar-sm avatar-circle">';
?>
```

in html i added the script that show alert but it didn't work it gives nothing

```
function mine(a,b){
swal(a, b);
        return false;
}
```

note that when i use the same function in this way it reveal the message normally but i want to adjust message content

```
function mine(){
swal("hi","hello");
        return false;
}
```

what is wrong with script

Comment: *"any help please"* No. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: Wrap the query output in quotes.  `swal(hello, world);` won't work, but `swal("hello", "world");` will.

Comment: What does the `swal()` function do?

Comment: @Archer but i cannot quoting variables in script ,right ?

Comment: @trill swal() a javascript for alert from here https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#configuration

Comment: @Archer how i embed variables (a,b) between quotes ? cause ("a","b") will just show letters not variables value

Comment: In your php, add escaped single whotes around the vales being passed to the function. When it renders it should look like onclick="mine('subject', 'body text')" right now it looks like the rendered HTML will send confusing data to the JavaScript without quotes around the string data

Comment: @Doug nothing happened i had done these changes but still nothing happens , code from inspecting page through chrome <a href="#" onclick="mine('hi','hello');">

Comment: Take out the swal() call for a minute -- drop an alert in there and see if calling `mine()` is even hitting the function.  If it is not, try moving the JS declaration to either the start or end of the HTML document.

Comment: @Doug thanks alot it sound that there was a repeated declaration for the JS and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$sub='$row["message_subject"]';
$body='$row["message_body"]';
echo '<a href="#" onclick="mine($sub,$body);"><div class="sl-item unread-message"><div class="sl-avatar avatar avatar-sm avatar-circle">';
?>
```